# How to get output of function returning Maybe?

Tags: haskell

This is a newbie question.

I am having a trouble understanding the output of StripPrefix function which returns Maybe [a].

What I am doing is, I am passing two strings to StripPrefix so that it gives back the string after cutting the prefix.

What I have tried is :

```
let b = stripPrefix pref stri

Just b <- stripPrefix pref stri
```

In first case, my print operation (`putStrLn b`) throws error "Couldn't match type `Maybe [Char]' with`[Char]'"

Comment: Are you doing this in GHCi?  Try `let Just b = stripPrefix pref stri`, but be warned that if it returns `Nothing` then when you do `putStrLn b` it'll raise a different error because it won't have anything to put in the `b` variable.

Comment: @bheklilr Thanks! Any idea how to know when b is Nothing in this case?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the `maybe` function, which takes a default value and a function to apply to the inside of a `Just`, so you could do `putStrLn $ maybe "Prefix stripping failed.." ("Stripped: " ++) $ stripPrefix pref stri`.  If it fails, it prints an error message.  If it succeeds, it'll print the stripped string.

Comment: I have to do some more processing with b. So I need to know if it is nothing or has some value. I was using putStrLn for debugging. Can you please add your first comment as answer (with maybe solution to handle nothing as well), so that I can accept it?

Comment: If you import `Data.Maybe`, you'll have access to the functions `isNothing` and `isJust`, which take a `Maybe a` value and return a `Bool`.  There's also `fromMaybe`, which is equivalent to `fromMaybe defaultValue = maybe defaultValue id`

Comment: Looks like the answer is complete. Can you post this thread as an answer? :) Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>From the comments on the question:</sup>

In GHCi, if you want to extract the `a` from a `Maybe a` you have a few options.  First, if you're sure it will succeed with a `Just something`, you can do

```
> let Just a = Just 1
> print a
1
```

However, this can lead to problems if your operation is not successful

```
> let Just a = Nothing :: Maybe Int
> print a
*** Exception <interactive>12:5-20: Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern Data.Maybe.Just a
```

All this is saying is that the pattern matching you used failed.  How do we avoid this?  There's case statements:

```
> -- Enable multiline input (I have this in my .ghci file so it's always on)
> :set +m
> let maybeA = Just 1
|
> case maybeA of
|    Just x -> print x
|    Nothing -> return ()    -- Do nothing
|
1
```

But this is laborious.  Wouldn't it be nice if there was an alternative built-in to Haskell?  Fortunately, there is in the `Data.Maybe` module:

```
> import Data.Maybe
> :type maybe
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
> -- The -1 is our default value in case of Nothing
> print $ maybe (-1) id $ Just 1
1
> print $ maybe (-1) id $ Nothing
-1
```

There's even an easier function to use when all you want is either the value in a `Just` or a default value:

```
> print $ fromMaybe (-1) $ Just 1
1
```

But `maybe` is more powerful in general:

```
> print $ maybe 0 (\x -> 2 * x - x * x * x + 7 ^ x) $ Just 3
322
```

There are still times, though, that all you want to know is if an operation was successful.  For that, `Data.Maybe` has `isJust` and `isNothing`:

```
> isJust $ Just 1
True
> isJust $ Nothing
False
```

And `isNothing = not . isJust`, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()` and `b :: Maybe String`. `putStrLn` expects its first argument to be a `String`, and that's not what `b` is. You can use `print :: Show a => a -> IO ()` to print a `Maybe` value, provided that the type it contains is itself `Show`able.